# This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I need to get reviews from google business account and display into my website .

```
I have used below curl method "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=$api_key&placeid=$place_id" to get google business reviews.
 I have correctly provided api key,place id also enabled Google Maps Geocoding  and Geolocating . I have got below error. How can I fix?`

Error :  
[error_message] => This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_
    [html_attributions] => Array
        (
        )

    [status] => REQUEST_DENIED
```

Comment: You need to setup api key it is necessary to access api.

Comment: the error message is very clear, whats the problem?

Comment: You need to go to you developers console dashboard, at the very top there's a link to the API library. There you can search and enable the places API. Your Project has no APIs by default, you have to enable them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue after I enable the API "Places API". Click on the option "ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES" as per image below. Search for "Places API" and enable this services. It should fix your issue.

In my case, I had enabled the "Places SDK for Android" and I was trying to call the Places API using the url below but it wouldn't work as I need the "Places API" to be enabled.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=YOUR_KEY

[image]

[image]

Comment: I fixed this issue after I enable the API "Places API". Good catch.

Answer (score -2):

For low volume / test usage you do not need google api key. You can get rid of the key for your testing - while you are getting a google API key. See the code running without google map key: https://plnkr.co/edit/5n66pLOC2rjJbl06tQ7C?p=preview

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```